# Tmux printing ^P

Tags: zsh, tmux

My terminal has recently started printing control characters (e.g. `^P` or `^N`) when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (or other combinations). I'm not sure what caused the change. [Here](https://gist.github.com/emandres/c252530ec5638f800a77) is my `.tmux.conf` file. Any ideas?

Note that `^C`, `^D`, and a few others still work as expected.

**Edit**
I just realized that it works when using `bash` inside of `tmux`, but not with my usual `zsh`. Any ideas?

**Edit 2**
I think this was a load order problem. In my `.zshrc` I set `EDITOR=vim`, which causes zsh to switch to vim keybindings. However, for a normal terminal session, apparently it was being set too late, but when `tmux` is run, a new `zsh` process is started, and this time `EDTIOR` is already set to vim, so it switches to vim keybindings. Putting `bindkey -e` right after `EDITOR=vim` in my `.zshrc` fixed the problem.

Comment: Please check, if `bindkey -v` or more specifically `bindkey '^P' up-line-or-history` makes `CTRL+P` working again.

Comment: The second command makes it work again, however ^N still doesn't work. Could this be tmux switching readline to vi mode? And if so, how do I switch it back to emacs mode.

Comment: zsh isn't using readline, but zle. Have you tried `bindkey "^N" down-line-or-history` accordingly? Have you updated zsh, installed oh-my-zsh or something similar lastly?

Comment: Regarding emacs keybindings, try `bindkey -e`.

Comment: @mpy I think that solved my question. If you put that in an answer, I'll gladly accept it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keybindings in the Z shell are controlled via the *bindkey* builtin. To enable the usual *emacs* or *vi* keybindings use `bindkey -e` or `bindkey -v`, resp.

You mention that you included `EDITOR=vim`into your zshrc file. This influences the default choice for the key bindings as explained by the *zshzle* manpage:

> If one of the `VISUAL` or `EDITOR` environment variables contain the string *vi* when the shell starts up then [the main keymap] will be *viins*, otherwise it will be *emacs*.  bindkey's -e and -v options provide a convenient way to override this default choice.

Comment: similar to OP's Edit 2 comment, I also use vim but had to use `bindkey -e`. `bindkey -v` didn't work